# 5 minute timer output time remaining

Tags: arduino-ide, timers, adafruit

I am trying to create a timer that outputs the time remaining in minutes. I am using an Adafruit Circuit Playground Express. 
For example, if the timer is 5 minutes, then every minute it should output the time remaining, until the time ends.

5 minutes timer started.

Delay: 5 minutes

Delay: 4 minutes

Delay: 3 minutes

Delay: 2 minutes

Delay: 1 minute

This is my attempt to implement this. I would like it to start by displaying  "Delay: 5 minutes"; however, this is not output until 1 minute has passed.

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
const long interval = 1 * 60 * 1000UL;  
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;           
int minutes = 5 ;

 unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  while (minutes >= 0){
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    Serial.print(F("Delay: "));
    Serial.print(minutes);
    Serial.println(F(" minute(s)"));
    minutes = minutes - 1;
  }
  }
```

Comment: `it does not output the correct remaining time` is not a useful description of the output .... it would be much more useful if you say what the output actually is

Comment: Also, h ow is previousMillis defined and initialized?

Comment: Same question was asked and is being discussed here  https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=632900.msg4285177#msg4285177

Comment: why are you posting your question here? ... the Arduino forum is giving you good suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Try this: (I don't have an Arduino here so i can't test it)

```
int minutes = 5;
int passedminutes = 0;
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  while((millis() - minutes*60000) < 0)
  {
    if(millis()%60000 == 0)
    {
      Serial.print("Remaining Time: ");
      Serial.println(minutes-passedminutes);
      Serial.println();
      passedminutes++;
      delay(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `millis()%60000` is fragile, because the `millis()` counter skips some values. Roughly one every 42 values.